# UISearchDisplayController and ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When I scroll main table view and if display search bar controller by `[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]`,

then "**Cancel**" and "**x**" buttons not working. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the `UISearchBarDelegate`?

Then use this method

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
}
```